# Plot the sine and cosine functions

Tags: java, math, graph, pi, trigonometry

I'm currently having some problems regarding my homework.

Here's the Exercise:

> (Plot the sine and cosine functions) Write a program that plots the sine function in red and the cosine function in blue.
>
> **hint:** The Unicode for Pi is **\u03c0**. To display -2Pi, use g.drawString("-2\u03c0", x, y). For a trigonometric function like sin(x), x is in radians. Use the following loop to add the points to a polygon **p**

```
for (int x = -170; x <= 170; x++) {
    p.addPoint(x + 200, 100 - (int)(50 * Math.sin((x / 100.0) * 2 * Math.PI)));
```

> -2Pi is at (**100, 100**), the center of the axis is at (**200, 100**), and 2Pi is at (**300, 100**)
>   Use the drawPolyline method in the **Graphics** class to connect the points.

Okay, so the sin function I have is a little different from the one in the exercise but it works so it shouldn't be a problem. The cosine function on the other hand, I'm having trouble finding the code for it so I don't have that in my program.

What I also need to do is place -Pi and Pi on the graph on their respectable places.

So, here's the code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Polygon;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Exercise13_12 extends JFrame {

public Exercise13_12() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(new DrawSine(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Exercise13_12 frame = new Exercise13_12();
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setTitle("Exercise13_12");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

class DrawSine extends JPanel {

    double f(double x) {
        return Math.sin(x);
    }

    double g(double y) {
        return Math.cos(y);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawLine(10, 100, 380, 100);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 190);

        g.drawLine(380, 100, 370, 90);
        g.drawLine(380, 100, 370, 110);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 190, 40);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 210, 40);

        g.drawString("X", 360, 80);
        g.drawString("Y", 220, 40);

        Polygon p = new Polygon();

        for (int x = -170; x <= 170; x++) {
            p.addPoint(x + 200, 100 - (int) (50 * f((x / 100.0) * 2
                    * Math.PI)));

        }

        g.drawPolyline(p.xpoints, p.ypoints, p.npoints);
        g.drawString("-2\u03c0", 95, 115);
        g.drawString("2\u03c0", 305, 115);
        g.drawString("0", 200, 115);
    }
 }
}
```

If anyone have the time to help me out I would be very grateful.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Well, i need to use the cos function the same way that i used the sin function and add a second line to the graph.

Comment: You are going to run into problems with the `g` function that returns the cosine, because you also use `g` for a `Graphics` parameter and the compiler will get confused.  Change the name of the function that returns `Math.cos`.  Or just use `Math.cos` without another function.  You don't really need `f`; you can change  the code that uses `f` to use `Math.sin` instead.  Same for `Math.cos`.  (Edit: Maybe the compiler won't get confused.  But a human reader certainly would.)

Comment: Thanks for answering @ajb, so i removed the `f` and the `g`. 
Now im getting this error.
"The method paintComponent(Graphics) is undefined for the type JFrame"

After removing `f` the code looks like this 
`for (int x = -170; x <= 170; x++) {
p.addPoint(x + 200, 100 - (int) (50 * Math.sin((x / 100.0) * 2 * Math.PI)));`

Could i be duplicating that for cos? (changing the `Math.sin` to `Math.cos` ?

Comment: @Khilmarsen yes, I believe you'd do the exact same thing for `Math.cos`.  As for the error about `paintComponent`: it compiles fine when I try the code you have posted; did you add another `super.paintComponent` somewhere outside the `DrawSine` class?

Comment: @Khilmarsen I added the last comment before I saw that you had gotten it working.  Great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Exercise13_12 extends JFrame {

public Exercise13_12() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(new DrawSine(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Exercise13_12 frame = new Exercise13_12();
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setTitle("Exercise13_12");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

class DrawSine extends JPanel {

    double f(double x) {
        return Math.sin(x);
    }

    double gCos(double y) {
        return Math.cos(y);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawLine(10, 100, 380, 100);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 190);

        g.drawLine(380, 100, 370, 90);
        g.drawLine(380, 100, 370, 110);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 190, 40);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 210, 40);

        g.drawString("X", 360, 80);
        g.drawString("Y", 220, 40);

        Polygon p = new Polygon();
        Polygon p2 = new Polygon();

       for (int x = -170; x <= 170; x++) {
            p.addPoint(x + 200, 100 - (int) (50 * f((x / 100.0) * 2
                    * Math.PI)));

        }

        for (int x = -170; x <= 170; x++) {
            p2.addPoint(x + 200, 100 - (int) (50 * gCos((x / 100.0) * 2
                    * Math.PI)));

        }

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawPolyline(p.xpoints, p.ypoints, p.npoints);
        g.drawString("-2\u03c0", 95, 115);
        g.drawString("2\u03c0", 305, 115);
        g.drawString("0", 200, 115);

        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawPolyline(p2.xpoints, p2.ypoints, p2.npoints);

    }
 }
}
```

[image]

Basically it's the same code all over, but you need a new polygon to draw it. And then I set the color using the setColor() function of the Graphics.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this to your `paintComponent` method:

```
        //Draw pi and -pi
        g.drawString("-\u03c0", 147, 100);
        g.drawString("\u03c0", 253, 100);   

        //Create a new polygon
        Polygon p2 = new Polygon();

        //Add the points of the cosine
        for (int x = -170; x <= 170; x++) {
            p2.addPoint(x + 200, 100 - (int) (50 * g((x / 100.0) * 2
                    * Math.PI)));
        }
        //Draw the function
        g.drawPolyline(p2.xpoints, p2.ypoints, p2.npoints);
```

With that you can have the results that you need.

Comment: Maybe you did not intend this, but I would avoid making the polygon and adding the points directly in the paintComponent method. I am thinking that paintComponent gets called for every repaint() issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so now that the program is complete i ended up with *this*.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Exercise13_12 extends JFrame {

public Exercise13_12() {
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(new DrawSine(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Exercise13_12 frame = new Exercise13_12();
frame.setSize(400, 300);
frame.setTitle("Exercise13_12");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);

}

class DrawSine extends JPanel {

double f(double x) {
    return Math.sin(x);
}

double gCos(double y) {
    return Math.cos(y);
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawLine(10, 100, 380, 100);
    g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 190);

    g.drawLine(380, 100, 370, 90);
    g.drawLine(380, 100, 370, 110);
    g.drawLine(200, 30, 190, 40);
    g.drawLine(200, 30, 210, 40);

    g.drawString("X", 360, 80);
    g.drawString("Y", 220, 40);

    Polygon p = new Polygon();
    Polygon p2 = new Polygon();

   for (int x = -170; x <= 170; x++) {
        p.addPoint(x + 200, 100 - (int) (50 * f((x / 100.0) * 2
                * Math.PI)));

    }

    for (int x = -170; x <= 170; x++) {
        p2.addPoint(x + 200, 100 - (int) (50 * gCos((x / 100.0) * 2
                * Math.PI)));

    }

    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawPolyline(p.xpoints, p.ypoints, p.npoints);
    g.drawString("-2\u03c0", 95, 115);
    g.drawString("-\u03c0", 147, 115);
    g.drawString("\u03c0", 253, 115);  
    g.drawString("2\u03c0", 305, 115);
    g.drawString("0", 200, 115);

    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.drawPolyline(p2.xpoints, p2.ypoints, p2.npoints);

  }
 }
}
```

**For anyone that might have the same problem as me later on.**

And thanks guys for helping me out, always grateful.

Answer (score 0):

check it out  .....

```
public class GuiBasicstest {    
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic herei
        guiBasics gb = new guiBasics();
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setSize(500,500);
        jf.add(gb);            
        jf.setVisible(true);            
    }        
}    

................................................................................
package guibasics;    
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author ALI
 */
public class guiBasics extends JPanel{
    //Graphics g = null;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        //super.paintComponent(g);
        for(double i = 0; i<200;i++){
            double y= Math.sin(i);
            draw(i,y,g);
        }
    }
    private void draw(double x , double y,Graphics g ){ 
         double x1, y1;
         x+=10;
         y+=10;
         x*=10;
         y*=30;

       x1=x+1;
       y1=y+1;
       Double d = new Double(x);
       int a = d.intValue();
       int b = (new Double(y)).intValue();
       int c = (new Double(x1)).intValue();
       int e = (new Double(y1)).intValue();
       g.drawLine(a, b, c, e);
    }
}
```